# How to read back and print text with newlines from a Python (Django) string with HTML?

Tags: python, html, django, newline

If someone types in a phrase, such as:

```
I see you driving

round town with the girl I love,

and I’m like: haiku.
```

(no blank lines between each line, but the text is written on three separate lines) into a text box on a web page, and then presses a button which is then stored in a database via `Django`, and that string is read back and printed on a page, how can I get it to print on an HTML page with the newlines still in the text?

So instead of it being printed back as:
`I see you driving round town with the girl I love, and I’m like: haiku.`

It would print as:

```
I see you driving

round town with the girl I love,

and I’m like: haiku.
```

I know that if I use: `(textarea)soAndSo.body(/textarea)`, this preserves the newlines that were in the file when the user typed it up originally. How can I get this same effect, but without having to use `textarea` boxes?

Answer (score 4):

While having linebreak symbols `\r\n` replaced with a `<br/>` is definitely an option, you may want to consider [css `white-space` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/white-space):

```
#haiku {white-space:pre;}
```

[Fiddled](http://jsfiddle.net/ovfiddle/DCsRj/), worth noting that [the property is surprisingly well-supported](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/whitespace.html), even on IE6+

Answer (score 2):

Wrapping the output in `<pre>` will preserve formatting, `<pre>soAndSo.body</pre>`

A more advanced solution involves turning the newlines into HTML paragraphs or line breaks. Django has built-in filters for this: Both [linebreaks](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaks) and [linebreaksbr](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaksbr) can do the trick.

If you want to use those, filter the output like so: `{{ soAndSo.body|linebreaks }}`

Answer (score 2):

Use the [linebreaksbr](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaksbr) (or [linebreaks](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaks)) filter in your template.

> For example:
>
> `{{ value|linebreaksbr }}`
>
> If value is `Joel\nis a slug`, the output will be `Joel<br />is a slug`.

Answer (score 0):

The newlines are there, it just doesn't do anything in HTML.

Use a filter like `{{ content|linebreaksbr }}`